# MSBuild - how to mark a target to run even if an AfterTargets fail

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I have a target that's marked to run after Build target runs:

```
<Target Name="MySolutionAfterTarget" AfterTargets="Build" >
```

However what I notice is when Build fails it doesn't execute my target, does anyone know how can I mark my target so it always runs.

Thanks,

Comment: This seems to apply also to VS2015, have you found any solution so far?